# Getting the output of a script run on a remote server over ssh by a C# test

Tags: ssh, .net-core

I'm writing automation tests in .net core that will access a remote server running the application we're testing. I'm currently ssh-ing onto a remote server in the test to run a script that verifies certain data. I want to get the output from that script to my local machine, so my test can know whether that step passed or not.

I am using the Renci.SshNet tool to connect to the remote server.

Here is the code I run in my test to connect to the remote host, then send a command as a string.

```cs
string commandToRun = "/opt/scriptHome/scriptWithOutput";

using (var client = new SshClient(ipAddress, username, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.RunCommand(commandToRun);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RunCommand returns an object of type SshCommand and you can use its properties to check the result of your command for example:

```
var command = client.RunCommand(commandToRun);
Console.WriteLine(command.Result);
```